# Is there a coalesce operator for parameters?

Tags: c#

If `F` were "on" `a`, I could do this...

```
var obj = a?.F();
```

If `F` is not on `a`, I have to do this...

```
var obj = a == null ? null : MyFunc.F((A) a);
```

Or do I? Is there a more succinct way of skipping the method call if a parameter value is null?

Comment: Just coalesce the values.

Comment: `if (a is A something) { MyFunc.F(something); }` Brevity without clarity is the start of many bugs.

Comment: @Davesoft I don't want `a` though, I want `MyFunc.F(a)`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's not quite as tidy if `F` returns a value.

Comment: Could you not just put the null guard inside F()?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer What a good idea.

Comment: I would prefer an explicit null check before calling the function. You could put the null check inside the function - return null if `a` is null - but then it's less obvious that the final result might be a null value. If there's a chance of ending up with a null I'd rather have that be obvious.

Comment: @ScottHannen Yes, it doesn't feel quite right sending null off to a method knowing that it will definitely return null.

Comment: I'd be okay with knowing that the other method will return null. The problem is not knowing it. If I'm calling `var obj = F(a)` and there's a chance that `obj` will be null, I'd want to know that. Of course I could look at the method, but that's an extra moment, and the next person will probably look at it too. Although I suppose the problem is ultimately just the pervasive possibility of nulls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no, there's no succinct way to do that.

The slightly longer answer is still no, but there's an interesting language design point here. C# was designed by people with extremely good taste, if I say so myself, but it was designed over a very long period of time. Nowhere is this more obvious than with respect to its treatment of nullability.

In C# 1.0 we had a straightforward language in the tradition of C, C++, Java, JavaScript, and so on, where there are references and values, and references can be null. This has benefits; if it did not, Sir Tony would not have invented the null reference in the first place. But it has downsides: we have the possibility of null references, dereferencing null leads to program crashes, and there is an inconsistency between reference and value types: reference types have a natural "no value" value, and value types do not.

In C# 2.0 we added nullable value types, but nullable value types do not behave like nullable reference types. Of course nullable values types are not references, so you cannot "dereference" them, but if we squint a little, the `.Value` property looks a lot like "dereferencing", and it leads to a similar crash if the value is null.  In that sense, they behave the same, but in other senses, they do not.  Adding together two nullable integers does not crash if one of them is null; instead, the result is also null.

So at this point we have a contradiction built into the language:

**Using a null value of a nullable value type usually automatically propagates the null, but using a null reference can crash.**

And of course C# has then gone on to add a variety of features that make null references behave more like null values, like `?.` and the related operations. There are also proposals for C# 8 that are very exciting, and will support "non nullable reference type" scenarios.

But the bolded text above is the fundamental problem you've pinpointed: the semantics of operators on nullable reference types are almost always "lift the non-nullable version of the operator to nullable types; if all the operands are non-null then the result is the same as the unlifted version; otherwise, the result is null".  However, those semantics are **not** automatically extended to the `.` member access operator or the `()` call operator, regardless of whether the operands are nullable value types or nullable reference types. `.` can be lifted explicitly by `?.` but the `()` operator does not get lifted to nullable semantics, ever.

Imagine a language like C# 1.0, but with `Nullable<T>` built in from the start, such that it applied to both reference and value types. In that world, you can see natural ways to implement generalized lifting, where if you have a method

```
class C { string M(double, int[]) }
```

and you call it with a `Nullable<C>` receiver, or `Nullable<double>` and `Nullable<int[]>` arguments, you automatically get the code that we build for you for nullable integer arithmetic: check whether the receiver or any arguments are null, and if they are, result in a null `Nullable<string>`. Otherwise, call the function normally and use the non-nullable result.

The C# compiler *already* implements these semantics for all user-defined operators declared on struct types; it would not be hardly any difficulty at all to extend those semantics to other kinds of methods. But we can't do it now; there are far too many backwards-compatibility issues to solve.

This design choice would also have the nice property that it would be a correct implementation of the "maybe monad".

But that's not the world we are in, and it's largely because these design considerations evolved over time, rather than being invented all at once. The next time you invent a new language, consider carefully how to represent nullability!